# Perl: Composition of a Variable of Hashes

Tags: file, perl, variables, hash

I have to parse a text file and put the information together.
My main problem is this data structure inside the external text file:

```
# Text file 
$basket = [
          {
            'Apple' => 'red',
            'Banana' => 'yellow',
            'Grapes' => 'purple'
          },
];

print "$basket[0]{'Apple'}\n";
```

Obviously I am getting an error message as this is neither an array nor a hash. Still I need to print out the Values to my keys. But this only works when using my own code:

```
# My input #
my %fruits = (
             'Apple' => 'red',
             'Banana' => 'yellow', 
             'Grapes' => 'purple');

print "$fruits{'Apple'}\n";
```

Does anyone have a clue how to access the value 'red' when referencing the text file.

Comment: You need to dereference the array reference first: `$basket->[0]{Apple}`

Comment: You forgot to account for the array (`[]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is an array reference, not an array. So you need to use an extra piece of syntax (an arrow, `->`) to dereference it.

```
$basket->[0]{Apple}
```

See [perldoc perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol) and [perldoc perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) for more information.